# Python Beginners error

Tags: python, qt-designer, pyqt5

I have this really "big" code

```
class ClassePrincipal(object):

    def __init__(self):

        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(464, 501)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 427, 719))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_3)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_4)
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_4)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_5)
        self.lineEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_5)
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_6)
        self.lineEdit_6 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName("lineEdit_6")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_6)
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_7)
        self.dateEdit = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.dateEdit.setObjectName("dateEdit")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.dateEdit)
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_8)
        self.lineEdit_8 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_8.setObjectName("lineEdit_8")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_8)
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_9)
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.radioButton_4 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.radioButton_4.setObjectName("radioButton_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.radioButton_4)
        self.radioButton_3 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.radioButton_3.setObjectName("radioButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.radioButton_3)
        self.radioButton_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.radioButton_2.setObjectName("radioButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.radioButton_2)
        self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.radioButton.setObjectName("radioButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.radioButton)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_10)
        self.lineEdit_7 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_7.setObjectName("lineEdit_7")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_7)
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_11)
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_12)
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.graphicsView)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_4)
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_5)
        self.horizontalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_6")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.pushButton_5)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.comboBox)
        self.lineEdit_9 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_9.setObjectName("lineEdit_9")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.lineEdit_9)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_6)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.scrollArea, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 464, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuArquivos = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuArquivos.setObjectName("menuArquivos")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionSalvar = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSalvar.setObjectName("actionSalvar")
        self.actionClose = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionClose.setObjectName("actionClose")
        self.actionClose_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionClose_2.setObjectName("actionClose_2")
        self.menuArquivos.addAction(self.actionSalvar)
        self.menuArquivos.addAction(self.actionClose)
        self.menuArquivos.addAction(self.actionClose_2)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuArquivos.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.actionClose_2.triggered.connect(MainWindow.close)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Nome do Solicitante"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CNPJ"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Email do Solicitante"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Razão Social"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Endereço do Solicitante"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Endereço do Serviço"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Data"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Valor so Serviço"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Forma de Pagamento"))
        self.radioButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "RadioButton"))
        self.radioButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "RadioButton"))
        self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "RadioButton"))
        self.radioButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "RadioButton"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Equipamentos Usados"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Descrição do Serviço"))
        self.label_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Imagem"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Procurar..."))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enviar via Email"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Salvar"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Cancelar"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Busca Banco de Dados"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "CNPJ"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Nome do Solicitante"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Data"))
        self.menuArquivos.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Arquivos"))
        self.actionSalvar.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Salvar"))
        self.actionClose.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Apagar"))
        self.actionClose_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Close"))

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    Mw = ClassePrincipal()
    Mw.show()  
    app.exec_()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But I'm having this error msg

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Alexandre/Documents/Python/FinalmenteUltimo.py", line 221, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Alexandre/Documents/Python/FinalmenteUltimo.py", line 215, in main
    Mw = ClassePrincipal()
  File "C:/Users/Alexandre/Documents/Python/FinalmenteUltimo.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.setupUi(self)
  File "C:/Users/Alexandre/Documents/Python/FinalmenteUltimo.py", line 17, in setupUi
    MainWindow.setObjectName
AttributeError: 'ClassePrincipal' object has no attribute 'setObjectName'
```

But, I've been reading about this module, and there is this attribute.

Can someone help me, I'm realy noob about python, This is my firt program, and I have no idea what is happening.

Since now, thank you.

Ps: I used QT Designer.

Comment: Shouldn't `ClassePrincipal` be inheriting from some QT class?

Comment: And yes, in the original code there is some Import statements

Comment: There's no second argument to `setupUi` in the `__init__`

Comment: What Should I put there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it, to fix that i just did

instead:

```
class ClassePrincipal(object):
```

I used

```
class ClassePrincipal(QMainWindow):
```

Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message implies, there is an error in line 17:
I guess you mistakenly wrote 'MainWindow.setObjectName' two times, but the first time without parameter. So Python is "thinking" you refer to an attribute with this name instead of a method and the underlying class does not have such an attribute (as described in the error).

Comment: Sorry abot this, my real code dont have this line, I posted by mistake, there is only the complete line

Comment: and just so u know, If I comment this right line, a second error occurs, the same error but now with resize

Answer (score 0):

I believe this file is generated by pyuic5. You should avoid editing computer generated file by hand. If you have .ui file you can try to generate py file using pyuic5 link below might help you out

http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html

Can you make your class extend QMainWindow and change the parts with MainWindow to self  like below  in setupUi. If this doesnt work create your file using Main Window option use -x flag on pyuic5 it will give you executable python code which is better option. also the link below should be helpful

```
    self.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    self.resize(464, 501)
```

http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/simple-text-editor-pyqt4/

Comment: I do not edit, I just add the main part, the same way in this web page u posted.